# Some questions concerning a C integer to string function

Tags: c

Whilst reading through K&R, I came across the *integer to string* function. I gave it a quick read, and decided to implement it myself, but instead of printing, it updates a character array.

Here is what I have

```
void inttostr(int number, char str[]) {
    static int i;  
    if (number / 10) {
        inttostr(number / 10, str); 
    }       
    str[i++] =  number % 10 + '0';      
}
```

It seemed to work for the few integers I gave it, but I have some questions.

1. I haven't explicitly included the nul byte `\0` at the end, so why does the string work fine when printed with `printf("%s\n", str);`?
2. I don't think I'm very good at *thinking recursively*. When I try and step through the program in my mind, I lose track of what is still awaiting execution. Is there a better way of seeing what is happening internally, to help me learn?
3. Any other suggestions on the code?

I'm using Xcode.

This is **not** homework. I'm just learning.

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use itoa()?

Comment: @Alexander If that is something in a standard library, then you are probably correct. However, I'm learning by doing, so calling the library function won't let me learn how it may work internally.

Comment: `itoa` is not standard, and it seems like this is an educational exercise.

Comment: `itoa` is not a standard function, but (for future reference) `sprintf` is.

Comment: "I don't think I'm very good at thinking recursively" - the combination of recursion with a static local variable made me pause a second. Maybe try re-writing without that, but instead `inttostr` returns the number of characters it has written. It might then be easier to consider the recursive steps separately, since they no longer share state. You will then be tempted to have two functions - one which nul-terminates and a self-recursive one which doesn't.

Comment: For thinking recursively, try writing out the stack frames. That is: just add a group of bins at the top for each call and strike it out on each return. Each group of bins has one cell for each argument which is filled in with the actual arguments and one cell for each automatic variable which is only initialized if the code does so explicitly. Static variables, however, exist only once and are not recreated in each stack frame, so put them off to the side...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct that you're never writing NUL, which is a bug.

In general, you don't have to think through the entire solution.  You just have to make sure every step is correct.  So in this case, you say:

1 . `inttostr(number / 10, str);`

will take care of all but the last digit.

2 . Then I will take care of the last one.

You can trace what's happening, though.  For e.g. 54321 it looks like:

```
inttostr(54321, str); // str = ...;
inttostr(5432, str); // str = ...;
inttostr(543, str); // str = ...;
inttostr(54, str); // str = ...;
inttostr(5, str); // str = ...;
str[0] = '5'; // str = "5...";
str[1] = '4'; // str = "54...";
str[2] = '3'; // str = "543...";
str[3] = '2'; // str = "5432...";
str[4] = '1'; // str = "54321...";
```

Note that when you don't return from any of the functions until you write the first character, then you return in the opposite order from the calls.

The ... signifies that you haven't NUL-terminated.  Another issue is that you're using a static variable, so your code isn't reentrant; this means it breaks in certain scenarios, including multi-threading.

To address the reentrancy and NUL issue, you can do something like the code below.  This creates a helper function, and passes the current index to write.

```
void inttostr_helper(int number, char str[], int *i)
{
    if (number / 10) {
        inttostr_helper(number / 10, str, i); 
    }       
    str[(*i)++] =  number % 10 + '0';
    str[*i] = '\0';
}

void inttostr(int number, char str[])
{
  int i = 0;
  inttostr_helper(number, str, &i);
}
```

EDIT: Fixed non-static solution.

Comment: Thanks Matthew. So, do you know why it may still be printing correctly despite not being nul terminated? I have since added the line `str[i] = '\0';`.

Comment: @alex, you just got "lucky.  If you do a `memset` before-hand (e.g. `memset(str, '-', num_chars);` it will be easier to see the problem.

Answer (score 2):

1, Your compiler (especially in debug mode) may have filled str with 0. Unix does this if you allocate memory with new() - But don't rely on this, either set the first byte to \0 or memset everything to 0

2, paper + pencil. Draw a table with each variable across the top and time down the side.

3, Write the simplest, longest version first, then get clever.

Comment: Thanks Martin. For 1, should I include the `\0` at the end to be sure it will work on all machines. For 2, when you say *time*, do you mean level of recursion it is in?

Comment: I thought that unixes tended to clear memory only when it is first allocated to the process (or used as stack). If your program has previously freed some memory (or been that deep on the stack), then even with this measure in place, you can allocate memory which isn't zeroed, instead it contains whatever you (or the call stack) left there. Yes, you should always write the 0 byte yourself, don't rely on implementation-specific behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

I am impressed of the creativity to use recursive, despite that it is not necessary. I think the code should remove statically-allocated i variable because this variable will persist through calls. So the second time you use this function from your code, e.g. from main(), it will not be initiated and will be the same value from previous call. I would suggest using return value as follow:

```
int inttostr(int number, char *str) {
   int idx = 0;
   if (number / 10) {
        idx = inttostr(number / 10, str); 
   }       
   str[idx++] =  number % 10 + '0';
   return idx;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> - I haven't explicitly included the nul byte \0 at the end, so why
>     does the string work fine when printed
>     with printf("%s\n", str);?

how is the original char array declared when you call your function the first time? if it is a static char array then it will be filled with 0's and that would explain why it works, otherwise its just "luck"

> - I don't think I'm very good at thinking recursively. When I try and
>     step through the program in my mind, I
>     lose track of what is still awaiting
>     execution. Is there a better way of
>     seeing what is happening internally,
>     to help me learn?

honestly, I am not sure if anybody is good in thinking recursively :-)

Comment: I declared it as `char str[30]`. Does this mean each of the 30 members will have a null byte? As for the second one, well you know what I mean! :)

Comment: It only means that you allocated room for 30 bytes. Their initial values are NULs only if `str` is declared as a global or static, but not if it is an automatic.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try drawing the execution step by step?

Comment: I did, and it sort of *clicked*. But I thought there may be a better way than that.